# would a css grid framework be a good fit for creating application like layouts?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, compass-sass

I have a webapp that I am making and it has some particular layout needs that are closer to an application than a website.

The layout has:

- a left sidebar that is fixed to the left side of the browser window and has a static width until it stacks, this sidebar will have tabs in it
- a content area that will expand to a certain max-width and then stop
- a right side bar that is fixed the the right edge of the content

I've been struggling to really determine if using a grid system, like bootstrap, would be an appropriate fit for something like this. Having some rows/columns and a collapsible grid in the content area seems like it would make sense, but in the sidebars it seems like its best to not use a grid system at all. I don't particularly like the idea doing some layout in the html with bootstrap3 and some in css.

Basically my app has the same layout as http://qz.com/ and I want similar responsive design breaks, and with that I would like to know if there is one or more css frameworks that support that type of layout with little overriding.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: it seems to me like there could be a general consensus about when the usage of a css framework like bootstrap becomes more of a burden than a benefit. For instance, if these frameworks are more directed towards center positioned website and the layout of those, then perhaps a project with multiple fixed positioning blocks would not be a good fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have some experience with resposive design and media queries, i would code it myself to avoid the thousands of lines of unnecessary code that comes with frameworks/libraries. bootstrap is great, but it also requires a bit of effort to master, and it would be a bit overkill for this one layout (if i understand you correctly).

if you just need this one layout, i would really recommend you do code it from scratch (personally i'd use something like jQuery and LESS). i hope i understood your question correctly, and sorry if this was not very hands-on.

to sum it up: in my opinion you're probably better off coding it yourself, but bootstrap and other frameworks will provide valuable insight and inspiration for how to do it.